# iPhone - Peculiar problem in using view controller when network is not there

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I'm using navigation controller and few view controllers. I'm pushing the view controllers to show them.
One peculiar problem with it is that, if internet is available, its working fine. When internet is not there, when I call "pushViewController", its crashing displaying the following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/satya/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/DDB23E6B-5723-44AC-B942-EA684E2A1E2B/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'StoreDirectoryListViewController''
```

I couldn't identify the problem.
I'm sure that XIB is created properly and it is with in the app itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to add more detail to help diagnose the problem. Your surrounding code when you `pushViewController:` would be helpful, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
First of all, in the database access, I'm opening, but didnt' close them and so lots of database opens were there.
Also I am creating IBOutlets for the view controllers in XIB. I removed them and using instance variables. This solved my problem. But I really couldn't identify how wifi is related for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Is the xib linked properly in IB?